# Why does my selenium function work sometimes and others not? Can I run it infinitely until it works?

Tags: python, selenium

I've a function that downloads an excel file depending on some values in two dropdowns by doing some clicks. I'm using selenium and it works because i have run it and it does exactly what i need, but sometimes it fails with different exceptions and I don't know why, if I try it 10 times it can fail 1 or 2. If I don't find a solution i was thinking on doing some sort of condition that runs the function until it doesn't get an exception.

```
url = "https://www.coordinador.cl/operacion/graficos/operacion-real/generacion-real-del-sistema/"
def download_generation(month, year, driver):
    driver.get(url)
    driver.find_element_by_id('tipo-xlsx').click()
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_element_by_id('tipo-xlsx').click()
    time.sleep(9)
    driver.find_element_by_id('datepicker777-9761_2').click()
    dropdown_month = Select(driver.find_element_by_class_name('ui-datepicker-month'))
    time.sleep(1)
    dropdown_month.select_by_visible_text(month)
    dropdown_year = Select(driver.find_element_by_class_name('ui-datepicker-year'))
    time.sleep(1)
    dropdown_year.select_by_visible_text(year)
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#ui-datepicker-div > div.ui-datepicker-buttonpane.ui-widget-content > button.ui-datepicker-close.ui-state-default.ui-priority-primary.ui-corner-all').click()
    time.sleep(1)
    download = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#Collapse2 > div > article > div.row.margin-top-3.cen_box-filter > div > div > form > div > div:nth-child(4) > a')
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", download)
```

Comment: Without seeing the exceptions, we can only guess at the problem...

Comment: As mentioned by John, we need to know what exceptions do you see, on what code line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things to be noted down.

1. You have a duplicate line of code here  `driver.find_element_by_id('tipo-xlsx').click()`
2. You should use `Explicit waits` for `stability`.
3. `CSS looks brittle`. See for better locator below.

**Code :**

```
url = "https://www.coordinador.cl/operacion/graficos/operacion-real/generacion-real-del-sistema/"
def download_generation(month, year, driver):
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    driver.get(url)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "tipo-xlsx"))).click()
    time.sleep(2)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "datepicker777-9761_2"))).click()
    dropdown_month = Select(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "ui-datepicker-month"))))
    time.sleep(1)
    dropdown_month.select_by_visible_text(month)
    dropdown_year = Select(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "ui-datepicker-year"))))
    time.sleep(1)
    dropdown_year.select_by_visible_text(year)
    time.sleep(1)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[class*='ui-priority-primary']"))).click()
    time.sleep(1)
    download =  wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[class$='download-file-marginal']")))
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", download)
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```